# Operation priorities in `assign` operation?

Tags: verilog

Usually, `assign` statements are simple and straightforward. But suppose there is a complex one that has parenthesis and concatenation and a bunch of different operators; What is the exact order of evaluation priorities of the operators that come on the right side of an `assign` statement?

There are a bunch of different operator types:

- `arithmetic`
- `logical`
- `relational`
- `equality`
- `bitwise`
- `reduction`
- `shift`
- `concatenation`
- `replication`
- `conditional`

In other words, if you were to convert an `assign` statement into an `always` block, what is the exact order of organizing the operations?

### Answer

Thanks to [@dave_59](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2755607/dave-59), based on IEEE's documentation, the priorities in descending order are:

| Operator | Associativity |
| --- | --- |
| `()`, `[]`, `::`, `.` | Left |
| `+`, `-`, `!`, `~`, `&`, `~&`, `|`, `~|`, `^`, `~^`, `^~`, `++`, `--` (unary) |  |
| `**` | Left |
| `*`, `/`, `%` | Left |
| `+`, `-` (binary) | Left |
| `<<`, `>>`, `<<<`, `>>>` | Left |
| `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `inside`, `dist` | Left |
| `==`, `!=`, `===`, `!==`, `==?`, `!=?` | Left |
| `&` (binary) | Left |
| `^`, `~^`, `^~` (binary) | Left |
| `|` (binary) | Left |
| `&&` | Left |
| `||` | Left |
| `?:` (conditional operator) | Right |
| `–>`, `<–>` | Right |
| `=`, `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, `%=`, `&=`, `^=`, `\|=`, `<<=`, `>>=`, `<<<=`, `>>>=`, `:=`, `:/`, `<=` | None |
| `{}`, `{{}}` | Concatenation |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 11.3.2 Operator precedence of the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595) defines this in detail.